# How to get data from local data with JS

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I have a data.js file in my local and I want to show my data in console. I tried with fetch don't get any data. Here is my **data.js** file.

```js
var TABLE_DATA = [
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "cony #5",
    thumbnailUrl: "image/5.gif",
    price: 170
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "cony #1",
    thumbnailUrl: "image/1.gif",
    price: 170
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "cony #2",
    thumbnailUrl: "image/2.gif",
    price: 270
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    name: "cony #8",
    thumbnailUrl: "image/8.gif",
    price: 70
  },
  ]
```

I have tried with below code but didn't work.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", getTableData);

function getTableData() {
  fetch("json/data.js")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Then I tried with axios. With axios data is showing but it is showing full data with variable name.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", getTableData);

function getTableData() {
  axios.get("json/data.js")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
  });
}
```

Below snippet is data is showing in console.

```js
var TABLE_DATA = [
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "cony #5",
    thumbnailUrl: "image/5.gif",
    price: 170
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "cony #1",
    thumbnailUrl: "image/1.gif",
    price: 170
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "cony #2",
    thumbnailUrl: "image/2.gif",
    price: 270
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    name: "cony #8",
    thumbnailUrl: "image/8.gif",
    price: 70
  },
  ]
```

**Now how can I get data with axios or without axios?**

**This is data.js file https://api-learning.netlify.com/json/data.js**

**Here is my demo in the browser and please check console https://api-learning.netlify.com/**

Comment: your JS file isn't a JSON file. Change your `data.js` to `data.json`, and keep the raw array data in that (make sure you adhere to [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) syntax)

Comment: @NickParsons I know it is not json file. I want to get data from js file. data.js file works fine in react js. So I want to try with vanilla js to get data. Is there any way to get data from js file?

Answer (score 1):

Woah, hold on there a minute. If you're storing data, you don't want to be using a regular old JavaScript file. Instead, put your data in a JSON file.

**`data.json`**

```
[
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "cony #5",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/5.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "cony #1",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/1.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "cony #2",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/2.gif",
    "price": 270
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "cony #8",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/8.gif",
    "price": 70
  }
]
```

Notice that the keys are now in double quotes. *That's important*.

There's a whole bunch of ways to load JSON data into a JavaScript file, but it's pretty dependent on what kind of environment you're working in:

- In Node, it's simply the `require` module.
- In jQuery, the `$.getJSON()` function call.
- Outside of those, the Fetch API and Axios can work, but I'm sure there's other options.

Take a moment to getting familiar with JSON, and figure out which method of loading it locally works best for you.

Comment: I participated in a job recruitment test. They provided me this file. That's why I tried this way. Thanks.